# Sharing counter values between MapReduce mappers

Tags: mapreduce, synchronization

I have a mapper that reads input and writes to a database. I want to limit how many inputs are actually converted and written to that database, and all mappers must contribute to the limit and then stop once that limit is reached (approximately; one or two extra isn't a big deal.)

I implemented a limiter function on our mapper that asks the other tasks, "How many records have you imported?" Once a given limit is reached, it will stop importing those records (although it will continue processing them for other purposes.)

the map code in question looks something like this:

```
public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable key, Result row, Context context) {
  // prepare the input
  // ...

  if (context.getCounter(Metrics.IMPORTED).getValue()<IMPORT_LIMIT){
    importRecord();
    context.getCounter(Metrics.IMPORTED).increment(1l);
  }

  // do other things
  // ...
}
```

So each mapper checks to see if there is more room to import, and only if the limit hasn't been reached does it perform any importing. However, each mapper itself is importing up to the limit, so that for 16 mappers, we get 16*IMPORT_LIMIT records imported. It's definitely doing SOME limiting (the count is much much lower than the normal number of imported records.)

When are counter values pushed to other mappers, or are they even available to each mapper? Can I actually get somewhat real-time values from the counter, or do they only update when a mapper is finished? Is there a better way to share a value between mappers?

Answer (score 0):

Okay: from what I've seen, MapReduce doesn't share counters between mappers until the job is finished (ie. not at all.) I'm not sure if mappers that commit partway through will allow later mappers to see their counters, but it's not reliable enough to be done real time.

Instead what I'll do is I will run a simple java application that iterates over the rows on its own and write to a column, which the existing MapReduce job will use to determine if it should import the row or not.